# How can bath tissue be both "100% recycled" and "50% post-consumer recycled material"?

Tags: recycling, hygiene

While shopping for bath tissue at the store today I saw Seventh Generation brand with this information on the label:

> Seventh Generation **100% recycled** bath tissue minimum **50% post-consumer recycled** paper

[image]

**How can both of these things be true?**

Ultimately I went with a cheaper brand that had only one fact on the label -- 90% post-consumer recycled paper.

Comment: Fun fact: There are usually limits to how much of a product contains post-consumer materials for materials like paper because paper degrades over multiple recycling processes, unlike say, glass or aluminum.

Comment: Not just the product itself, but similar label can be found on packaging box like "The Arm & Hammer Pure Baking Soda" had: Box made from 100% recycled paperboard, minimum 35% post-consumer content.

Answer (score 6):

The other 50% is recovered process waste - material that has been processed and recycled before it was ever sold to the consumer. It’s all recycled, but originates from different phases of the product lifecycle.

Further reading:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-consumer_recycling